# Where are the extension function for Android Context?

Tags: android, android-ktx

As android developers we use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)` or `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes)`.

To make this simple, we created extension function on `Context` as such:

`inline fun Context.getCompatColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int): Color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)`

This is very useful so I was wondering whether this is currently in `Android KTX` library. I keep looking for it but I can't find it. Is it there? if its not why isn't it there?

Comment: just a small fix 
`@ColorInt
inline fun Context.getCompatColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int): Int =
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the extension functions for `android.content.Context` in core-ktx:

`systemService()`: Return the handle to a system-level service by class.

`withStyledAttributes()`: Executes block on a TypedArray receiver.

https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.content/android.content.-context/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list - it seems there is no such thing in libraries from Google

Usually you can append `-ktx` to some library to get kotlin extensions for it, so for example when looking for `Context.getCompatColor` I would check `androidx.core:core-ktx` (because `ContextCompat.getColor`  is in `androidx.core.content` package). But it doesn't have any such thing https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list#androidxcorecontent

Answer (score -3):

try `Context.resources.getColor()` it will solve your problem